# Get Isolated Storage path for UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have learned about [Isolated Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage). I want to store my SQLite Db in Isolated Storage. How can I get isolates Storage path for UWP app.

Comment: Isolated storage is, well, isolated.  Only the one application has access to the store.  The actual location isn't documented, and isn't available from the code via a public variable.  You can see it in the debugger within the instance of the IsolatedStorageFile that you might create as `m_RootDir`.  For example, in my app, it's at `C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\xaqvzfek.qea\tfjliuls.4ui\Url.yxyzgfhgzg0iasl33mri5zetabnqgue0\Url.yxyzgfhgzg0iasl33mri5zetabnqgue0\Files` .  It isn't designed for your use case at all.  Put it in `Environment.ApplicationData`

Comment: @Flydog57 any way i can get isolated path without reflection as String ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf: Short answer: No. It's (intentionally) not exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to (or should) know the path to be able to create a file using the `IsolatedStorageFile` API:

```
IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storage.CreateFile("myfile.txt");
```

If you really want it, you could use reflection:

```
string path = typeof(IsolatedStorageFileStream)
    .GetField("_fullPath", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(fileStream)
    .ToString();
```

But you should not rely on the absolute path anywhere in your app.

Comment: Thanks for answer. To create `Sqlite db`  i need to send databasepath in DB constructor. Is  there any way i can get path without reflection? How can i create db with the path. I am using `sqlite-net-sqlcipher` package

Comment: No, there isn't and it's a reason for that: You should not rely on the path. Storing an SQLite database in isolated storage seems to be bad idea. But if you still want to do it, you can use the `path` variable from the answer.

Comment: So what's you suggestion to store `Sqlite Db` ? As Isolated Storage is secure then why its bad idea to store `SQlite Db` in Isolated Storage ?

Comment: Because it requires an absolute path that you don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

The article at your link clearly states that these APIs were deprecated long time ago and they are not available for Windows 8 and newer apps. If you are trying to build secure UWP app, store encrypted database in the one of special folders provided by [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) class and keep password in the [PasswordVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault?view=winrt-19041).